# How to search for elements inside JSON array of objects

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, filter

I am trying to create a search filter for accordion data which has to search in the title as well as the contents inside. It must search for the `name` key.

I have implemented a function for the same but with that approach, I am not able to search for `name` inside the `children` key.

```js
let filteredTiles = this.tileData.filter((value) => {  //tileData is the JSON array
    return value.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue) != -1 ? value : null;
});
```

How is it possible to search within the children from the JSON data?

[Demo at Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qg7lcj?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

My JSON data is

```
[
    {
      "name": "First",
      "image": "https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/football-2022-tournament-cup-background_206725-604.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Firstone",
          "image": "https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/hand-painted-watercolor-abstract-watercolor-background_23-2149005675.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg",
          "url": "http://www.google.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "Firsttwo",
          "image": "https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/hand-painted-watercolor-abstract-watercolor-background_23-2149005675.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg",
          "url": "http://www.google.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "Firstthree",
          "image": "https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/hand-painted-watercolor-abstract-watercolor-background_23-2149005675.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg",
          "url": "http://www.google.com"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Second",
      "image": "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/517188688/photo/mountain-landscape.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=A63koPKaCyIwQWOTFBRWXj_PwCrR4cEoOw2S9Q7yVl8=",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Secondone",
          "image": "https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/hand-painted-watercolor-abstract-watercolor-background_23-2149005675.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg",
          "url": "http://www.google.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "Secondtwo",
          "image": "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/517188688/photo/mountain-landscape.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=A63koPKaCyIwQWOTFBRWXj_PwCrR4cEoOw2S9Q7yVl8=",
          "url": "http://www.google.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "Secondthree",
          "image": "https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/hand-painted-watercolor-abstract-watercolor-background_23-2149005675.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg",
          "url": "http://www.google.com"
        }
      ]
    },

]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works similarly on how you filter the object in an array.

In the predicate, you have to filter the nested object in the array. If the filtering of a nested array return index greater than -1, means that there are nested object(s) that fulfill the filter criteria.

Besides, you can work with [`Array.some(predicate)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which returns boolean value as alternative of `Array.findIndex(predicate) > -1`.

```js
this.tileData.filter((value) => {
  return 
    value.children.some(
      (c) => c.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue) > -1
    )
  ;
});
```

If you want to filter whether the root object or nested children fulfill the filter criteria, you should use the `||` (or) operator.

```js
let filteredTiles = this.tileData.filter((value) => {
  return (
    value.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue) > -1 ||
    value.children.some(
      (c) => c.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue) > -1
    )
  );
});
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pwkmcx?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: With that approach if a value matches in nested children then all the nested children are being showed up instead of  only the ones which have that search value. How can we fetch only the nested children which consist of search value ?

Comment: For my working, after filter, I will use `Array.map()` to transform each object and perform filtering for matched objects in the `children` array. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pwkmcx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: How can I search for "name" in the main object and get all the children it has along with the above functionality as well?

Comment: Maybe this [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5v8dsf?file=src/assets/data.json) fulfills your requirement as the comment above.

Comment: I am not able to find any changes in app.component.ts in the Demo link. I think it is pointing towards an older version

Comment: Read the code in detailed. I had amend in the `children.filter()` part.